# Need to check for "string" in "response data"

Tags: jmeter, assertion

I need to check for string in response data.Lets say 'has been submitted' is the string and if it is not there i should stop the next request. I am planning to use Result status action handler. any other better solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Response assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as a child of the HTTP request and put your string in **Patterns to Test**

[image]